Swagger-UI No API definition provided
Even though I have made the Swagger settings correctly, it says No API definition provided in the UI.
All endpoints are available at http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>


@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/register/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/login/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/docs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(jwtService, userDetailsService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        
        return http.build();
    }

Data comes in http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs, but not in http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html. Why could it be?
Swagger image
